# Метод audio.save VK API возвращает invalid hash

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Первое что пришло в голову, что я отправляю неверный hash, однако hash, который я получаю до audio.save ([инструкция](https://new.vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9)) такой же, какой я отправляю методу audio.save. Вот как я делаю все($token="мой токен"):

```html
$server = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/audio.getUploadServer?access_token='.$token));$server = $server->response->upload_url;
$file = new CURLFile(realpath('files/temp.mp3'));

$chp = curl_init($server);
curl_setopt($chp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($chp, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($chp, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'file' => $file
));
$data = json_decode(curl_exec($chp));
$serveraudio = $data -> server;
$audioaudio = $data -> audio;
$hashaudio = $data -> hash;
curl_close($chp);
$musicadd = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/audio.save?server=".$serveraudio."&audio=".$audioaudio."&hash=".$hashaudio."&access_token=".$token));
```

Answer (score 1):

Пропустите параметры вызова метода `audio.save` через `http_build_query()`.

```php
$method = 'audio.save';
$request = array(
   'server' => $server,
   'audio' => $audio,
   'hash' => $hash,
   'access_token' => $access_token);

$request = http_build_query($request);
$request = file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/' . $method . '?' . $request);
```